# How to convert image with php gd image

Tags: php, image, gd

I want to convert the image to some pattern.

I have got that we can do it using the php gd library.

I have found one link where some function exist and output of that function is shown.

I want exact output but due to some lack of knowledge in php gd library uses, I am not able to use that code.

Can anyone help me that How do I use it?

The link for the script is : http://www.phpied.com/image-fun/

And I want the function under header "Black and White"

here is the sample of php function:

```
<?php
    function blackAndWhite($pixel, $factor)
    {
        $pixel_total = ($pixel->r + $pixel->g + $pixel->b);

        if ($pixel_total > (((255 + $factor) / 2) * 3)) {
            // white
            $pixel->r = 255;
            $pixel->g = 255;
            $pixel->b = 255;
        } else {
            $pixel->r = 0;
            $pixel->g = 0;
            $pixel->b = 0;
        }

        return $pixel;
    }

?>
```

Please tell me how do I use it?

to convert my images.

I have done this:

```
<?php

ob_start();

$name = "CharlieCarrMug.jpg";

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);

imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);

imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT);

imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -10);

imagepng($image);

imagedestroy($image);

// and finally retrieve the byte stream
$rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();
echo "<img src='".$name."' />";
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $rawImageBytes ) . "' />";
?>
```

But I want to use the above mention function in this.

Comment: Have you tired anything yourself or is the pasted code (from the site) all you've made so far?

Comment: I have updated my question. I have added the script which i had done till now. Please have look.

Comment: If you want to use the pixel plugin you have to use the pixel plugin (the `Image_PixelOperations` and `Pixel` class that you linked).

Comment: can you please provide any sample script for it??
or the reference link.

Comment: The reference link is the same one you linked: http://www.phpied.com/image-fun/